# Maven not moving a resource file on exec:java

Tags: maven, resources

I have 3 resources in my `/src/main/resources` folder:

```
┓ src/main/resources
┣━━━ magnetDatabase.csv
┣━━━ windingDatabase.csv
┗━━━ logo.png
```

When I run `mvn exec:java` all resources apart from `windingDatabase.csv` seem to be moved to `target/classes`.

The relevant parts of my `pom.xml` are below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>magnetDatabase.csv</include>
            <include>windingDatabase.csv</include>
            <include>logo.png</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

For both `exec:exec` and `exec:java` it does not copy this one resource file? I have checked the name of the file and it is correct. I keep having to manually copy it across which is *very* annoying

Comment: It looks like you are using maven-resources-plugin,aren't you? "By default, Maven will look for your project's resources under `src/main/resources`". It seems that you don't need `resources` section at all. Why is `src/main/java` in directory scheme?

Comment: Oops that was a typo :S I don't have a `maven-resources-plugin` I just have those resources at the end of my `pom.xml` which has worked up until now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mvn exec:java
```

[Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase validate prior to executing itself](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html).

You should compile your sources first:

```
mvn compile
```

It should also process your resources. [You may take a look at lifecycle reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

Comment: Ahh I see, it should work if I link compile phase to the execution phase too?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. Actually, any phase after process-resources should do the trick.